# Overwrite inline CSS Tag

Tags: html, css

After a migration of an existing Content Management System i have some problems with existing classes - sometimes the Richtext Editor created the following HTML Code:

```
<span style="font-weight: bold; "><a href=""....>
```

Now, the Link is not bold, but i dont know if it is possible to overwrite any rule in CSS when having a custom inline Style property.

Is there any chance (without changing the HTML Code) to make the link as bold text?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Thanks for the first comments - but to be sure i want to add the "bold" tag only when ill have this "special" inline property.  So i dont want to overwrite all classes with bold text.

When i have

```
 <span><a style="font-weight: bold;">....</a>
```

Everthing is fine, the Link is bold

But when i have

```
 <span style="font-weight: bold;"><a href="">....</a>
```

The link is NOT bold (but it should be bold).

This is little stupid Code from the Richtext Editor.

Comment: Try using font weight maybe and the !important, something like font-weight: 800 !important;

Comment: You could add `a { font-weight: inherit !important; }` to your CSS, although that will apply to all `a` tags.

Comment: Or set font weight with !imporant property

Comment: Always do a search before you ask questions.

Comment: Do you have other CSS rules that are overriding the CSS you've shown us?

Comment: No there should be nothing.

Comment: Hmm thats a little weird - there is no class (shown with firebug) to do anything, but it works without any CSS. Maybe there is a problem with Firebug which is not showing me all Classes for the Element.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Original:

Use `!important` :

```css
span {
  font-weight: normal !important;
}
```

```html
<span style="font-weight: bold; ">
  <a href=""....>
    link
  </a>
</span>
```

---

## Edit:

This means that in your CSS, there is somewhere :

```css
span {
  font-weight: normal !important;
}
```

You need to overwrite it by selecting the `span` with more **specificity** than the declaration in the current css, e.g:

```css
/* somewhere in the css you can't modify */
span {
 font-weight: normal !important;
}


/* the css you add */
.container span {
 font-weight: bold !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <span style="font-weight: bold; ">
  <a href=""....>
   link
  </a>
 </span>
</div>
```

The is because **classes**, **ids**, **attributes**, etc all have a score which add up to see which declaration will be used.

> Start at 0, add 1000 for style attribute, add 100 for each ID, add 10 for each attribute, class or pseudo-class, add 1 for each element name or pseudo-element.
>
> **- [smashingmagazine.com](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/)**

And here is an cheat sheet :

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but this is not my problem.

Comment: @derdida Added more details to answer your question. :)

Comment: Ill already found out the solution. Ill still know how to handle CSS Classes, but this time it was a little weird (because Firebug did not show any Classes which overwrite any rule) -> checked out without any rule and found out it works as expected. Then ill found out that a Class from another Module which was included overwrite this effekt with the "*" Selector. Problem solved, thanks for pointing me into the right direction. Sometimes it is hard if you are working for over an hour for a simple Problem, and then found out its just a simple display bug.

Comment: @derdida Always happy to help. We all have moments like that, just take a break, do something else for 20 minutes, and come back to check your code. :)

Comment: These are wise words. Thanks :)